# Bash Script read -p

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm pretty sure the answer is no but I thought I'd ask anyway. I want to have a bash script with a user input that automatically proceeds after the desired amount of characters are entered, in this case 3.

So when the user enters `123` or `abc`, the script moves on with that variable rather than waiting for an 'Enter'.

```
read -p 'User Input: ' userInput
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In bash, you can add `-n 3` or `-N 3` depending on the exact behavior you require. From `help read`:

> ```
>   -n nchars return after reading NCHARS characters rather than waiting
>             for a newline, but honor a delimiter if fewer than
>             NCHARS characters are read before the delimiter
>   -N nchars return only after reading exactly NCHARS characters, unless
>             EOF is encountered or read times out, ignoring any
>             delimiter
> ```

Comment: If I try adding -N 3 or -n 3 it says illegal option -n.

Comment: @AshtonWatts are you sure you are using `bash` - not `sh` (or `dash`)?

Comment: Yeah the problem was that I wasn't running it as bash. Working fine now.